# Setting Up Replication / master slave configuration to mariaDB

Tags: cluster-computing, mariadb, database-administration, buildbot

I'm starting my project using ***mariaDB***

1. I want to setup *master slave* configurations on windows 7 64Bit. I don't know how to setup this kind of configuration.

I've searched on google, visited websites and blogs, i find a term **buildbot**, is it related to master slave setup in mariaDB. ?
If my question has another solved answer please tell me so that i can move further. Thanks in advance. hope for positive response.

Answer (score 0):

Buildbot is a CI framework. It may be able to use mariaDB to store it's own data but it has nothing to do with mariaDB configuration itself.

Comment: so please can you tell me how can i setup master slave on mariaDB ? any idea about that ???

Comment: I've never used mariaDB but a quick google leads to [this site](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-documentation/replication-cluster-multi-master/replication/setting-up-replication/), which contains an example